# How i can catch data, sended by compiled flash applet to server?

Tags: flash, debugging, trace

I have some compiled flash applet (swf) on web page, which interact with remote server by sockets.
How i can catch sended data, without using complex sniffer, if possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Can you be more specific about it? Do you have access to the source code of the swf? Do you know the port number? There is a comprehensive example at [livedocs](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=17_Networking_and_communications_8.html) in case you missed it.